# Android String Post to PHP server

Tags: php, android, post

Summary 
-I take text from edittext and send it to server. And server put these strings to text file
-There is no visible error. 
-Server gets my post but it has onyl null string.

Here is my post code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
 new AlertDialog.Builder(GorusHataBildirimActivity.this)
  .setTitle("Bildirim Yola")
    .setMessage("Bildirim yollamak istiyor musunuz ?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
          try {
EditText isim = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText mesaj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
String a = isim.getText().toString();
String b = email.getText().toString();
String c = mesaj.getText().toString();
String s = "Debug-infos:";
String k = "Debug-infos:";
if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {

s += "\n OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")" + "\n OS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
}else {
s= "0";
}

if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {

k += "\n Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE + "\n Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " (" + android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";
}else {
k = "0";
}
HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost getMethod=new HttpPost("http: my  url /bildirimler/bildirim.php");
try{


List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isim","dsa"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",b));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mesaj",c));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("d1",s));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("d2",k));
getMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
client.execute(getMethod);


} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
          } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
});

thread.start();
```

i think this code (android side ) does not work correctly.

here is php code

```
<?php

$dateFile = date('d-m-Y_hia').".txt";

$dataString = "isim:" . $isim . "mail:" . $mail.  "mesaj:" . $mesaj.  "d1:" . $d1. "d2:" . $d2.  "\n";
$fWrite = fopen($dateFile,"a");
$wrote = fwrite($fWrite, $dataString);
fclose($fWrite);
print "file created and written to";

?>
```

Moreover ,
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isim","dsa"));
in there i used "dsa" instead of using string name like  a  b  c  ( my strings in my code ) but stil doesnt work.

my output file is like
    "isim:mail:mesaj:d1:d2:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to properly capture the data in the PHP code.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['isim']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['mesaj']) && isset($_POST['d1']) && isset($_POST['d2'])) {

 $isim = $_POST['isim'];
 $mail = $_POST['email'];
 $mesaj = $_POST['mesaj'];
 $d1 = $_POST['d1'];
 $d2 = $_POST['d2'];

 $dateFile = date('d-m-Y_hia').".txt";

 $dataString = "isim:" . $isim . "mail:" . $mail.  "mesaj:" . $mesaj.  "d1:" . $d1. "d2:" . $d2.  "\n";
 $fWrite = fopen($dateFile,"a");
 $wrote = fwrite($fWrite, $dataString);
 fclose($fWrite);
 print "file created and written to";
} else {
 print "missing required input";
}

?>
```